# Запустить и остановить bat файл по кругу

Tags: python

помогите с скриптом который запускает .bat файл, через 30 минут закрывает этот файл, проверяет закрылась ли бат файл и если закрылся тогда сразу запускает опять bat файл. итак по кругу.
Спасибо.

Comment: А вам точно не проще разместить инструкцию перехода goto с задержкой в 30 минут прямо в .bat?

Comment: если вам не трудно, напишите пож как что куда

Comment: Так в тексте вопроса написано "помогите", а с чем конкретно помочь-то? Полный код я вам все равно не смогу написать

Comment: Ну вообще-то батч запросто может сам запускать следующую свою копию, внешнее управление тут не требуется.

Comment: @denisnumb
Я же написал что мне требуется.

Comment: Т.е. вы хотите чтобы кто-то подорвался и сделал за вас вашу работу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
:A

"Сюда твой код"

timeout /t 1800

goto A
```

Время в секундах.

Comment: :A
@echo off
cd %~dp0telegram_bot
python main_bot.py
pause
timeout /t 10
goto A

Comment: получился такого вида

Comment: @echo off :A cd %~dp0telegram_bot python main_bot.py pause timeout /t 10 goto A

Comment: @echo off перед всем

Comment: :A \@echo off cd %~dp0telegram_bot \@echo off python main_bot.py \@echo off pause @echo off timeout /t 10 goto A

Comment: сайт не даёт, отправить комменты такого вида без экранирования.